# How to get rid of Log[e] from mathematica output?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

My mathematica output is

```
-0.751988 - 0.0708732 Log[e] - 0.0140273 Log[e]^2
```

But I want mathematica to calculate this expression for me i.e. set Log[e] = 1 and sum the terms. How do I instruct it to do that. I'm assuming it must be treating the functions as complex??

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably wanted [`E`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/E.html) or [`\[ExponentialE]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/ExponentialE.html) which has the [input alias](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputAliases.html) `⋮ee⋮`.

Answer (score 4):

Built-in symbols are capitalized, so constants like pi, e are written as Pi, E

Answer (score 2):

If i remember correctly, Mathematica use E as the Neper number, not e. I think you mispelled it, so Log[e] is not expanded.
If not so, with the substitution Log[e]->1 you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I used esc e esc to typeset base e, but the substitute rule worked ... thanks